# How to take available space using container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, singlechildscrollview

I was trying to make an app with SingleChildScrollView and ListView using below code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              maintile(),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return listitem();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

but the listview holding container does not take available space If I provide Expandable around it. is there any way to achieve Container take available space?

Comment: you should set size for Column and wrap ListView inside Expanded

Comment: how to know the full screen height of the device and put it to column?

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size gives you the device screen size.

Comment: but not working..

Comment: remove shrinkWrap: true,

Comment: can you add your methods? maintile() and listitem()

Comment: when removing shrinkwrap: true, cause exception -  RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (22807): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter (22807): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis

Comment: I am updating it one by one. @Maz341

Comment: Is it possible that you show what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the MailTile(), how about you post your listItem() too so i can write the code for you

Comment: I am not a native english speaker. So sorry for my english. I want a scrolling list with listview just shown like above.

Comment: It is okay! Please update your listitem() method

Comment: 1 minute. What is happening actually, my scaffold have different color so if listview container dont take whole space left. scaffold color will be shown.

Comment: in ItemBuilder Inside your Listview i want to see the method  listitem();

Comment: listitem added...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Expanded` for `Container` parent like this :

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Text("YOUR_WIDGET"),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Final Code:**

```
final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: screenSize.height,
        width: screenSize.width,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            maintile(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return listitem();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
  ),
);
```

Comment: if screenSize won't work then remove height : screenSize.height to double.infinity and same for width

Comment: this is not what I want. I want to scroll everything including listview, that's I include SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Then your root would be first SingleChildScrollView then Container

Comment: I mean when I scroll main tile and listview both scrolls, that's why I disabled ListView scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `ListView` inside an `Expanded`? & removing the one around the parent `Container`. That's what I always do to make my ListView fill the space.

Comment: I want the container, Expanded working only inside of Column/Row?